# Disabled input button use modal on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have the following input button:

```
 <div class="DisabledCart">
     <input type="submit" id="StandardProductAddToCart" name="Add to Cart" value="ADD TO CART" alt="Add to Cart" style="cursor:not-allowed;" disabled="disabled"/>
 </div>
```

That I'd like to pop up my modal if clicked.

JS:

```
 $(".DisabledCart").click(function (evt) {
     $('#NotAvailable').modal('show');
 });
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="NotAvailable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="NotAvailableLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <img class="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/x_white.png" height="20" width="20" alt="X" />
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Not Available</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="subscribetext">Not available for online orders. Please call 1-800-543-8995 to order; thank you.</p>
      </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I click the button, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not just using `data-toggle="modal` on the submit button instead? I mean, why do you trigger it manually?

Comment: @callmekatootie What does that do? Does it automatically pop up the modal instead of on click? I'm doing on click because if a user clicks it, I want to display some kind of feedback letting them know why clicking it didn't do anything for them.

Also, somehow, this began working out of the blue.

However, Firefox & Safari do not work.

Comment: Did you try it out? The documentation clearly mentions its use: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals - See the code for the Live Demo section